# Get local names with reverse geocoding?

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim, reverse-geocoding, mapquest, germany

I am using the reverse geocoding service provided by MapQuest.

For a sample coordinate of `N 53.27, E 8.13`, I receive the state of "Lower Saxony". According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_Saxony), and a user of my service, the German answer is "Niedersachsen".

Using the [MapQuest API](http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/), is there any way to change the language of the results service?

Alternatively, if I can't do that using the MapQuest API directly, is there a web based translation service that could be suggested to make that translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `accept-language` parameter as described in the [official Nominatim documentation](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Reverse/#language-of-results).

> `accept-language=<browser language string>`
>
> Preferred language order for showing search results, overrides the
>   value specified in the "Accept-Language" HTTP header. Either use a
>   standard RFC2616 accept-language string or a simple comma-separated
>   list of language codes.

Comment: This answer lead me to the correct answer, which I have posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use nominatim, instead of the MapQuest Geocoding version of Nomination. Change the URL from http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/reverse to http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/reverse , and it should work fine. Noet that other changes might be required. Here's an example:

http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/reverse?lat=52.27&lon=8.973333&accept-language=de_DE

Some help from [this form question](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/480771) was provided.

Comment: Please keep in mind that OSM's Nominatim instance and MapQuest's Nominatim instance have different usage policies! The [usage policy of OSM's Nominatim instance](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Usage_Policy) is more strict because it runs on donated resources. Therefor your solution won't work for everyone.

Comment: The one I provided is nominatim directly on MapQuest, it's not the OSM Nominatim. There's 2 versions of the MapQuest Geocoding API based on Nominatim, their own version, and the OSM version.